# Separate PHP String of football results (1:4 in $var1 = 1, $var2 = 4)

Tags: php

How can I separate a PHP string of e.g. football results into two variables?

I could do it with `substr($res, 0,1)` and `substr($res,2,1)` but then it might cause a problem, if the football game result has two digits, to `14:3` or `13:16`.

Does anybody have an idea how to separate a string into two values if the string is separated by an ":"? The : shall be removed.

Comment: Use a `list()` construct.. `list($a,$b) = explode(':',$footballstring);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[explode()](https://www.php.net/explode) is used to convert your string to array by specifying some delimiter.

```
$string="14:4";
$arr=explode(":",$string);
echo "Team 1 Score= ".$arr[0];
echo "Team 2 Score= ".$arr[1];


//o/p will be
Team 1 Score= 14
Team 2 Score= 4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [explode](http://php.net/explode) to do this :

```
$str= "1:4";
$arr= explode(":",$str);
echo $var1 = $arr[0];//will output 1
echo $var2 = $arr[1];//will output 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split values into array using explode